# What percentage of war (card game) games end?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

In [War (card game)](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/War_(card_game)), assuming cards are put into the bottom of the pile when taken (and make whatever other assumptions you want\need to make the question easier), what percentage of games end, and do not go on an infinite loop?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231948/is-war-necessarily-finite?rq=1

You are asking a refinement of this problem, which is already an open problem. As such, nobody knows!

Comment: War! What is it good for? Absolutely nothing!

Answer (score 0):

Under some randomness assumption, it seems like it is 0% of the games (the length of the game is claimed to be finite) https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11503/does-war-have-infinite-expected-length